Criteria for determining duplicate questions
There is a question with the same title but I'm sure my question is different.

If a question is not answered, will another newly asked question be considered the duplicate question?
If a question is answered but not solved, then the new question is considered as duplicate question?
If a answer is no longer applicable due to changes to the system being asked about, then the new question will be considered as duplicate question?
If you are not satisfied with all the answers to a question, does post a new question count as a duplicate question?

Are these considered duplicate questions? If so, how should the new OP solve their question?
The questions I'm talking about are all questions with the main site, not Meta.

A question is a duplicate if the answer to another question answers the question. It’s up to the author of the new question to be specific enough in their description to make it clear the existing answer doesn’t answer their question. Sometimes authors of questions don’t actually know better

An old question can also become a duplicate if a new question + answer covers it, or answers it better. I think the criterium is easy (in theory): where's the best answer to a question (question A)? If that answer belongs to another question (question B) then question A is to be marked as duplicate of question B, the rules allowing.

No, answers don't expire, but some do have a best-before date since libraries, ideologies, and languages do change. How we used to do stuff retains value, lot of people maintaining legacy systems, but for new development how things worked back in 2008 may no longer apply. We count on folks who have close privileges knowing enough to dupe-close appropriately, and in the cases where the top-voted answer has been superseded, direct the asker to the most appropriate answer.

What Stack Overflow lacks is a sense of versioning. Some attempts have been made but it remains sketchy and error prone to do. I would never consider answers to expire. Ever. In fact the older an answer gets, the more value it has. The reason is simple, old technology is like a weed. Cobol programmers are still desperately needed today. I'm sure at some point in the future Java developers will be in a similar demand. Preserving information about old stuff is wickedly important. BUT. It does add the problem of it being harder to separate old from new, if all you're interested in one of the two.


You cannot close a question on the Main site as a duplicate of another unless it (the duplicate target) has an answer with a score of 1 or more or an accepted answer. (The only exception to this is if the author of the question is the same user.) On Meta a question does not need to be answered, let alone have an answer with a score of 1+, to be a duplicate target.
If the question author has accepted an answer (questions aren't "solved" here) is irrelevant. Accepting can only be actioned by the author and is completely optional. Also the accepted answer may not the "best" (most upvoted) answer (and even the most upvoted can actually not be the "best"™). Questions aren't closed as a duplicate of an accepted answer but of a question, as it contains 1+ "good" answers. It is up to the reader(s) to try and test those answers and see which works best in their environment. Though a user who VTC'd may wish to comment on the question they are voting to close to point to a specific answer if they know it's most relevant.
Answers do not have an expiration date. Based on original question.
If the answers are no longer relevant then asking a new question is ok, if you explain well enough how it differs; posting the same question as an existing one, with no explanation on why it differs, will likely result in closure. Also, for this scenario, bounties are an excellent tool.
If you feel your question is not a duplicate, use the Edit feature to improve your question to demonstrate and explain why it is not a duplicate; "The other question doesn't answer this problem.", or similar statements aren't good enough for that.
Should you appropriately improve your question, the community, or a "gold badger" will likely reopen your question. Note, as well, if your question was unilaterally closed by a gold badger, you can "ping" them in the comments of the question (though the prompt doesn't appear); therefore you could edit your question and then ping them in the comments to let them know you've addressed why the question isn't a duplicate.

Also, if you do find you are asking the same question as an existing one, and the answers don't feel appropriate, you always have access to the bounty feature to attract users to revisit the question and, hopefully, address the reasons why you have added a bounty.

re: 1/2, I can't immediately find a source for this, but I believe that duplicate targets need a positively scored or accepted answer (that is, it is sufficient for the answer to be accepted without being positively scored).

@RyanM as far as I know, the only documentation for this is in the error message provided by the vote-to-close-as-duplicate interface.

@RyanM You are correct that questions with an accepted answer are also acceptable duplicate targets. FYI. in the network Meta's FAQ How does duplicate closing work? When is a question a duplicate, and how should duplicate questions be handled? answer, there's "Unanswered duplicates: Generally, a question cannot be closed as a duplicate of a question with no upvoted or accepted answers, unless:

the site is a meta site
the questions were posted by the same user
a moderator closes the question"


Generally, API changes will cause answers to expire. Is the new question considered a duplicate at this point?

You cannot close a question on the Main site as a duplicate of another unless it has an answer with a score of 1 or more.  Sorry, I don't quite understand what this means, and I saw a lot of duplicate questions being closed.

"Generally, API changes will cause answers to expire." Perhaps it would have been clearer what you meant in your question if you'd phrased it as something like "...is no longer applicable due to changes to the system being asked about".  "Is the new question considered a duplicate at this point?" Generally, no, it wouldn't be a duplicate; a new question should call out that it is asking specifically about newer versions, and that the old answers therefore no longer apply.

You mean that users can modify other people's questions and post bounties? So who does this question belong to? For example, if two user have different ideas about this question, who can modify it in the end?

@SageJustus one of the requirements with edits is that they shouldn't conflict with the author's intent. This does have some limits though where if the author insists on adding in fluff / meta content that does not belong in the question the community edits to remove such content are considered correct. In simpler words as long as an edit does not change the meaning of the post and generally improves it the edit is fine.

Sorry, I assumed you were familiar with the up/down vote and scoring system on the sites, @SageJustus , as you had close to 1k reputation; I felt it was a safe assumption you were aware of that mechanic. The score is the number on the left of the post, between the up and down vote buttons (the arrows). The question must have one or more answers to it where that score is 1 or more.

I know what scoring system. I mean Why is closing questions relevant to answer scoring? Whether or not the question is duplicate should be relevant to the question, why is it relevant to the answer? Also, why would answers with a score higher than 1 be closed? Does this mean that low scoring answer will not be closed?

Because for a question to be a duplicate target, on main, it must have an answer with a score of 1 or or, @SageJustus , as I stated. A question cannot be closed as duplicate (on main) of another question if that target question has no answers, or only zero (or lower) scored answers.

"Also, why would answers with a score higher than 1 be closed" Answers cannot be closed; only questions can be closed.

my bad. you said duplicate target, I thought it was duplicate question itself.


If a question is not answered, will another newly asked question be considered the duplicate question?
If a question is answered but not solved, then the new question is considered as duplicate question?

I assume that by "solved" you mean "has an accepted answer".
Whether a question "is considered as duplicate" is entirely up to those who flag or vote that way.
The system will permit a given question X to be closed as a duplicate of question Y, as long as Y has an accepted answer and/or an upvoted answer.
Note that old questions may be closed as duplicates of newer ones, whether or not the old question has answers. However, this is a rare occurrence, and usually happens as part of a cleanup effort even further down the road (when someone realizes the newer question was originally overlooked as a duplicate, and became more popular and received more editing attention).

If the answer to a question has expired, then the new question will be considered as duplicate question?
If you are not satisfied with all the answers to a question, does post a new question count as a duplicate question?

Answers can't "expire". If the existing answers on a question are demonstrably invalidated due to being obsolete (meaning: you can show that they used to work but don't any more), then it deserves new answers.
Please don't intentionally post duplicates. Instead, draw attention to the old question. This includes cases where an answer is needed that works with a new version of a library (assuming the existing answers all don't), or where the existing answers are unsatisfactory for some other reason.

then it deserves new answers. and Please don't intentionally post duplicates. You just said not to post new questions, but the new user's question has not been solved: The previous question is no longer active and no one has answered it.

Please read the immediately next sentence, where I explicitly tell you what to do instead, with a link and everything. "Activity" is not a thing here.

I'd take the position that if something has changed in the system such that the previous answers no longer apply, "How do I _____ in version ____ and above?" (with a specific explanation of why the existing answers do not address this) is not a duplicate.  In fact, I'd say it's better (given the platform's underwhelming handling of obsolete or otherwise version-specific answers) to have them separated into two questions, one for older versions and one for newer versions.

I asked @ThomA the same question: You mean that users can modify other people's questions and post bounties? So who does this question belong to? For example, if two user have different ideas about this question, who can modify it in the end?

about ativity, I mean the active tag or filter you use when browsing questions. In my experience, questions that are updated frequently are more likely to be seen.

"So who does this question belong to?" To the site and the community. That's why there's a license agreement.
